# how to match exact database timestamp with my date

Tags: php, mysql, database, date

Hi i have doubt regarding how i can exact match my `database` `timestamp` with my `date` i'm getting `date` from my `URL query string`   which looks like  this `2017-07-19`    and my stored `date`  in my `database` is `2017-07-19 13:40:23`

Below `query` returns `0` results despite i have this `created_at=>2017-07-19 13:40:23` `date` in my db

```
"SELECT all_data where created_at = DATE('2017-07-19')"; // db=> 2017-07-19 13:40:23
```

**Question:** how can i exactly match my `2017-07-19` with my `DB` `created_at`

```
2017-07-19 13:40:23
```

right now i'm getting `empty` result

please help thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: EaB  you got your answer or not?

Answer (score 3):

Your query is incorrect (strange that it din't raise any error to you).Need to be like this:-

```
SELECT * FROM `<table name>` WHERE DATE(created_at) = '2017-07-19'
```

Note:- put correct table-name there and check.

Answer (score -1):

2 ways you can match the date without timestamp:

1) Using DATE_FORMAT:

```
SELECT all_data FROM table WHERE DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y-%m-%d") = "2017-07-19";
```

2) Using Wildcard:

```
SELECT all_data FROM table WHERE created_at like "2017-07-19%";
```